# What is the "other wind"?

Tags: books, ursula-k-le-guin

What does the wind in the title of Ursula LeGuin's *The Other Wind* refer to?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's mentioned in the book's inscription

> Farther west than west
>   beyond the land
>   my people are dancing
>   **on the other wind.**
>   -- The Song of the Woman of Kemay

It seems to refer to the process of traveling to an astral plane rather than the mundane death of a character. Note that we see certain individuals come back when sufficient magic is used:

> "Life immortal," Seppel's soft voice took the word. He spoke smiling a
>   little. **"In a great land of rivers and mountains and beautiful cities,
>   where there is no suffering or pain, and where the self endures,
>   unchanged, unchanging, forever** ... That is the dream of the ancient
>   Lore of Paln."
>
> "Where," the Summoner said, "where is that land?"
>   **"On the other wind," said Irian. "The west beyond the west."** She looked round at them all, scornful, irate. "Do you think we dragons
>   fly only on the winds of this world? Do you think our freedom, for
>   which we gave up all possessions, is no greater than that of the
>   mindless seagulls? That our realm is a few rocks at the edge of your
>   rich islands? You own the earth, you own the sea. But we are the fire
>   of sunlight, we fly the wind! You wanted land to own. You wanted
>   things to make and keep. And you have that. That was the division, the
>   verw nadan. But you were not content with your share. You wanted not
>   only your cares, but our freedom. You wanted the wind! And by the
>   spells and wizardries of those oath-breakers, you stole half our realm
>   from us, walled it away from life and light, so that you could live
>   there forever. Thieves, traitors!"

In context, characters (especially dragons) claim to travel on the *other wind* to a mystical land of milk and honey. It's not especially clear if this is a metaphorical place or a literal place.

> **"Do dragons die?" asked Onyx, musing. "Not as we do, I think." "They
>   don't live as we do. They move between the worlds. So says Orm Irian.
>   From the world's wind to the other wind."**

Comment: Think Valinor / Heaven

Comment: More details about the Song of the Woman of Kemay can be found in book 4 of the Earthsea cycle, Tehanu.

Comment: @Richard Do you mean *LORE OF PA**L**N*?

Comment: @lexible - Sorted. Don't forget that you can make edits + corrections yourself by clicking the edit button.

Comment: @Richard Quite… but you are diligent and active, so I  meant it as a question, in case there was some subtle point you were making that escaped me.

Comment: @Lexible - Nope, just a typo in my copy evidently.